# How do I give a a custom color for a DIV element on Sublime-Text 3 (in the editor)?

Tags: html, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I've just set ST3 so every language will work on a different scheme but now I want that ONLY a DIV element will receive a custom color **on the editor** (since there are a lot of div's around HTML pages)? 
I tried to search for the answer and I found some answers but it involve with changing the HTML.tmLanguage file (and also..I didn't really understand the syntax there).

[Changing sublime text 3 html tag enclosure colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21323642/changing-sublime-text-3-html-tag-enclosure-colors)

I also bumped into this amazing Theme-Maker , but changing the "tags" relate to all tags and I only want to change the DIV's color.
http://tmtheme-editor.herokuapp.com

thanks

Comment: when you say 'change the colour'? do you mean how it displays in your editor? or how it displays on the webpage youre building?

Comment: On the editor.. thanks for the note :)

Comment: then Im afraid your question is off topic for stack overflow.  SO is for programming questions, not IDE or other software setup questions.

Comment: I'm new here so I am apologize for this , it's just that I saw this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21323642/changing-sublime-text-3-html-tag-enclosure-colors and I didn't think that it's wrong

Comment: @MattHolbrook-Bull you are incorrect. Questions regarding tools primarily used for programming are on-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you will have to write your own [syntax definition](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/syntaxdefs.html) to recognize your specific div element. By default all HTML divs are handled the same way. In your case you could extend the `HTML.tmLanguage` syntax definition. And then create a new color scheme (or extend an existing one) to color it the way you like.

This is how I would do it:

1. Create a new syntax `spcialdivHTML.tmLanguage`
2. [Include](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/syntaxdefs.html#the-patterns-array) the HTML syntax definition (so it gets extended)
3. Write your own [match pattern](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/syntaxdefs.html#the-patterns-array) logic to recognize your special div (and give it a scope name)
4. Extend a [color scheme](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/color_schemes.html) with the scope name from point 3
5. Select the new syntax definition for your file.

Note: This is all not done in 5 minutes especially if you are not confirm with syntax definitions and color schemes. And you really should consider if it is worth the work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... I guess that if it's too complicated, I leave the ST3 the way it's working now. But thanks again :)